# Why does Process.Start from my app causes Outlook to crash?

Tags: c#, outlook, 64-bit, system-tray, anycpu

I have an app that sits in the system tray and monitors certain events.  Upon a specific event, it fires off a Process.Start with a "mailto" link.  When that happens the Outlook New Mail window briefly comes up and then it crashes.

I am on a 64-bit Windows 7 box and the app is compiled as Any CPU.  I changed it to compile as x86 and Outlook no longer crashes.

Can someone provide insight as to why Outlook would crash if it was started from a 32 vs 64 bit process?  Seems like it shouldn't matter.

Comment: is there any entries in Windows "Event Viewer" describing error details ?

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim Yes, it does, but nothing really descriptive.  http://i.imgur.com/TrR59IY.png